# Why is the layout of an skscene is not the same in all devices

Tags: sprite-kit

**hi 
i want to make a brick shooter game and I started doing the border lines that are near the edges of the screen and I implemented the code(below) and it should work be the same on all devices but when I try it in an iPhone 8 everything goes fine and when I try it in an iPad or iPhonex it looks different like it zoomed in for some reason

Even the standard hello world label is the same

Can you please help me

And thanks **

```
    func crwalls(){
    //        for i in 1...3 {
    let spce = self.frame.width/12
    let wall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "liiine")
    wall.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: self.frame.height/1.5)
    wall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 30, y: frame.midY + (self.size.width/4) )
    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: ((wall.size.width)), height: ((wall.size.height))))
    //floor.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = floorbit
    wall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    print("mmm")
    self.addChild(wall)

    let wall3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "liiine")
    wall3.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: self.frame.height/1.5)
    wall3.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX - 30, y: frame.midY + (self.size.width/4) )
    wall3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: ((wall3.size.width)), height: ((wall3.size.height))))
    //floor.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = floorbit
    wall3.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    print("mmm")
    self.addChild(wall3)
    let wall4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "liiine")
    wall4.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width - 40, height: 20)
    wall4.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y:       self.frame.maxY - spce)
    wall4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: ((wall4.size.width)), height: ((wall4.size.height))))
    //floor.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = floorbit
    wall4.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    print("mmm")
    self.addChild(wall4)

}
‘’’
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree its annoying that Xcode doesn't have a 'do all option' to scale everything perfectly for all different device screen sizes.

Still here is something you might want to look into a little to see if these give you any better results:

[SKSceneScaleMode.apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscenescalemode)

So there are a few different options for scale mode that you can select. Have a play with the ones listed in the linked document. Just change the highlighted part in the GameViewController to what you would prefer

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = .**aspectFill**
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: thx for your help , i tried .aspectfit and it worked perfectly on all devices but it showed black space on some devices any way to overcome that ??

Comment: huh?  aspectFill is your "Do all option" to scale everything perfectly for all different device screen sizes.

Comment: @Heyguys,  If you are supporting all devices,  then you need to build your scene as a square.  If you are building just for tall devices,  then you need to build your scene in a 812/375 ratio (Thanks Apple).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to "Why is the layout of an skscene is not the same in all devices."

Because that would be impossible.  This is like asking why can't clothing stores sell just 1 size clothing.

Screens come in all shapes and sizes, so it is up to you to determine how it will appear to the user.

The most simplest solution is building your game with a square scene.  This will cover all aspect rations both tall and wide.

Of course, this may not be ideal to actual gameplay because you may end up losing more scene on the sides then you want.

Another solution is to make your SKView the reciprocal ratio of your scene and use .aspectFill on your view. This will make it so that your sides will show more information on wider devices, but your tall devices will receive the amount of information you want them to see.